# Azure Storage Account - temporary download link using container SAS

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-sdk-python, azure-sas

I'm working with Python Azure SDK and I run into the following problem.

What I'm trying to do is generate container SAS token to be used only on a given container, to do so I'm using Azure SDK `generate_container_sas`

```
def get_temporary_access_token(self):
    sas_token = generate_container_sas(
        self.account_name,
        self.container_name,
        self.storage_token,
        permission=ContainerSasPermissions(read=True, write=True, delete=True, list=True),
        expiry=datetime.utcnow() + self.sas_token_expiry_time
    )
    return sas_token
```

This returns a string looking something like `se=<end_datetime>&sp=<Permission>&sv=2019-07-07&sr=c&sig=<token>`

Now using this token I'm able to do all sort of things, but what I'm having trouble to do is using this link for temporary download link for a certain blob.

I was trying to do it using this method:

```
def get_temporary_download_link(self, blob_full_path, expires_time):
    base_temp_url = f'{self._get_base_resource_url()}/{self.container_name}/{blob_full_path}'
    token = generate_blob_sas(
        account_name=self.account_name,
        account_key=self.sas_token,
        container_name=self.container_name,
        blob_name=blob_full_path,
        permission=BlobSasPermissions(read=True),
        expiry=datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(seconds=expires_time)
    )
    return f'{base_temp_url}?{token}'
```

Now when I try to use the link I've built in the method above I'm failing in the following method `b64decode`.

From that I can understand that I'm not suppose to use SAS token for temporary download link and I can do this only by using the resource token or user delegation object?
I also tried to "fool" the method by encoding the SAS token but the URL resulting with an error `Signature did not match`

I didn't manage to find any documentation on what I can or cannot do with the resource SAS token vs the UserDelegationKey, anyone knows if it possible to use the resource SAS token for temporary download?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Basically the issue is that you're using a SAS token (in your case created for a blob container) to create a new SAS token. This is not allowed. You will need to use either the account key or user delegation key to generate a SAS token.

Also, you can use the SAS token generated for a blob container as a SAS token for blobs inside that container. If you create a SAS token for a blob container with at least `read` permission, you can use the same SAS token to download any blob in that blob container.

Comment: Yea I'm using the account key to generate SAS token, but you made me figure out that I can just use the SAS token as a suffix for downloading the blob without using `get_temporary_download_link`, thanks